# Can Searchmonkey find a term inside textfiles?

Tags: search, text, searchmonkey

Searchmonkey has a search option called "Containing".

[image]

What can it do? Can it find a term in text file?

Comment: Searchmonkey (0.8.3) packages for Trusty & Xenial avaibale from my [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ueter/+archive/ubuntu/searchmonkey/+packages); Peter B

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `searchmonkey` can search inside the selected file and the advanced settings and options contain ways of refining the search so that case is matched, ignored, or wildcards can even be specified. You can also construct your own regular expression to use if you have a particularly complicated search request.

You can save the search criteria and results to a file, but with `searchmonkey` you can't modify the file that you are searching within, and you have to open it with your text-editor as the [documentation notes](http://searchmonkey.embeddediq.com/overview).

`Regexxer`, however, has options to search for files, and also to search and replace the search terms from a selected document or a whole series of documents. It is a more complete substitute for command-line tools like grep, sed, etc, but you could certainly use both `searchmonkey` and `regexxer` for your various purposes.

Another bonus is that `regexxer` integrates into `Thunar` very nicely, unlike `searchmonkey`; all you need to use in the custom actions is to add `regexxer %F`, and right clicking on the folder will open `regexxer` in that particular folder.

See my answer here for more details on `regexxer` and its various functions:

- [Looking for a grep GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/228652/737582)

The screenshot shows the search within a text file with `searchmonkey`:

[image]

Comment: can they read inside pdf files (as recoll can)?

Comment: @cipricus regexxer can't read inside pdfs, and I don't think searchmonkey can either.

Comment: only txt i guess (not docs and such either)

Comment: @cipricus You should be able to search within html and xml files with both of them, but not office type documents, like .doc or .odt.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know, there is a new version of Searchmonkey available (0.8.3) that let's you look inside PDF files and the common word-processor files such as DOCX, ODT, DOC, etc.

We are currently working on making Searchmonkey even better, tighter and lighter, so please let me know if there are any new features or suggestions for the future of Searchmonkey.

Best,
Adam - Searchmonkey founder