# Search Files by Content

Tags: command-line, nautilus, search, dolphin

Is it possible to search for files including it's content for the desired keywords using Terminal, Nautilus or Dolphin?

Comment: GUI version for grep: https://askubuntu.com/questions/228565/looking-for-a-grep-gui

Comment: Do you know if it is able to also search Microsoft Office documents?